# Parabolicity of high order PDEs

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I know that the traditional classification of PDEs into parabolic, elliptic, and hyperbolic is applicable for the second order equations. However, I often see remarks about parabolicity  of higher order PDEs in various articles. In particular,  the equations of the thin film family are said to have the *"degenerating parabolicity"*.  For example,  [this paper](http://www.ima.umn.edu/preprints/pp1989/474.pdf) introduces the following *degenerate parabolic* nonlinear fourth order equation (in $1\mathrm D$):
$$
u_t + \nabla\cdot \left(\left\lvert u\right\rvert^p\,\nabla \Delta u\right) = 0.
$$

How do we formally define the parabolic, elliptic, and hyperbolic classification of high order nonlinear PDES?